# Activity asks to set width of screen

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have got this application from another developer and in Android Manifest these meta data were written.

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="design_width_in_dp"
        android:value="1280" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="design_height_in_dp"
        android:value="752" />
```

These meda datas as I understood correctly set the specific size of the screen for the Application. When I try to delete it one of my activities gives me the below error.

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.ergofox.scanner2v7a/me.ergofox.scanner.ScannerActivityDashboard}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must set design_width_in_dp  in your AndroidManifest file
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3437)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2041)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must set design_width_in_dp  in your AndroidManifest file
```

I would like to delete these meta data and specify for all type of screen Application. How can I do this ?

Comment: Neither of those are from Android. Some third-party library that you are using is requiring those. Look at the lines in your stack trace after the "Caused by" to try to determine what library that is.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your answer, I found a library which couased issue.  Library is implementation 'me.jessyan:autosize:1.1.2'

Comment: I'm VERY curious what this lib does.. can we manage `Activity`s size on really big screens?